# Проблемы с VK API

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу програмку на джаве с использованием vk api, и проблема с методом messages.send. Какой бы user_id в параметрах не вводил, все равно сообщения приходят на мой аккаунт. Начал грешить на код, но попробовал просто вбить ссылку в адресную строку браузера, и то-же самое.
Вот ссылка
https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=75784041&random_id=4563&message=privetloh&v=5.52&access_token=
Может я дико туплю и неправильно ввожу параметры?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: может ваш рандом не работает и возвращает одно и тоже значение?

Comment: Что значит "сообщения приходят на мой аккаунт"? Ваш аккаунт - это тот, на который был выдан токен? Или 75784041?

Comment: @michael_best Да вроде нет, в приложении корректный рандомизатор, но даже если он ошибочный, я же вот ручками ссылку в адресную строку вбиваю с разными значениями этого параметра, эффект все равно один.

Comment: @pavel На тот, на который был выдан токен, все правильно. Юзер айди ввожу разные - результат один

Comment: @СтёпаФомичёв, попытался воспроизвести проблему - не получилось. Сообщения приходят от Вас в диалог с самим собой, так?

Comment: @Pavel Да. Уже перебрал пару десятков айди и написал в техподдержку вк, общеали ответить через 37 часов)